# How to change didSelectRow Color from blue to orange?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Cell have already an image (of size 320 * 103) and text "Highs And Lows from The 'Raly To Restore Sanity And...." as shown in first cell.

My problem is that when I select any row for navigating to the detailsViewController the cellimage(of size 320 * 103) color should be change as like shown in below imageColor(orange color) (eg. third row). How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:--
put the code inside the given method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/256.0 green:199.0/256.0 blue:235.0/256.0 alpha:1.0];// change the color to your orange color i used different color herer
cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
[myBackView release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *cellBgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
cellBgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBgView;
[cellBgView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set `backgroundView` as others said. 
Second, when the cell is selected, it will call `-(void)setSelected:animated:` and `-(void)setHighlighted:animated:` of `UITableViewCell`. I suppose your cell is custom, subclassing from `UITableViewCell`.

I like to override the `-(void)setHighlighted:animated:` method, and inside the method, I will do following things.

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated 
  {
      [myLabel setHighlighted:highlighted];
      [myIconImage setHighlighted:highlighted];
      ///.... propagate the highlighted event to subviews.

     // Call super method.
     [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
  }
```